# Cobertura with Ant

Tags: java, ant, cobertura

I'm trying to run Cobertura with Ant, however always get this error in command line, 
Note I'm on OSX, I couldn't figure out my directories correctly in the build.xml. Why does the command line search in /Users/jia/Java/Cobertura/cobertura-2.0.3 when I have already set different paths on the build.xml

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/weimqu/Documents/workspace/Coverage1/build.xml:23: /Users/jia/Java/Cobertura/cobertura-2.0.3 does not exist.
```

Here's my build.xml

```
<project name="MyProject" default="coverage" basedir=".">
    <description>
        Ant build file
    </description>

    <!-- The properties are set in build.properties -->
    <property file="build.properties" />
    <property name="cobertura" location="../cobertura-src/cobertura-2.1.1" />

    <path id="junit.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${junit}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="cobertura.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${cobertura}">
            <include name="cobertura.jar" />
            <include name="lib/**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef classpathref="cobertura.classpath" resource="tasks.properties"/>

    <target name="init">
        <!-- Create the time stamp -->
        <tstamp/>
        <!-- Create the build directory -->
        <mkdir dir="${bin}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${instrumented}" />
        <mkdir dir="${reports.xml}" />
        <mkdir dir="${reports.html}" />
        <mkdir dir="${coverage.xml}" />
        <mkdir dir="${coverage.summaryxml}" />
        <mkdir dir="${coverage.html}" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init"
        description="compile the source " >
        <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${bin} -->
        <javac includeantruntime="false"
            srcdir="${src}"
            destdir="${bin}"
            debug="on">
            <classpath refid="junit.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="test1" depends="compile">
        <!-- Run junit tests -->
        <junit printsummary="yes" fork="yes" haltonfailure="off">
            <classpath location="${bin}"/>
            <classpath refid="junit.classpath"/>
            <formatter type="plain"/>
            <test name="edu.depaul.se433.BinarySearchTest"/>
        </junit>
    </target>

    <target name="instrument" depends="init,compile">
        <!--
         Remove the coverage data file and any old instrumentation.
         -->
        <delete file="cobertura.ser"/>
        <delete dir="${instrumented}" />

        <!--
         Instrument the application classes, writing the
         instrumented classes into ${instrumented}.
         -->
        <cobertura-instrument todir="${instrumented}">
            <!--
             The following line causes instrument to ignore any
             source line containing a reference to log4j, for the
             purposes of coverage reporting.
             -->
            <ignore regex="org.apache.log4j.*" />

            <fileset dir="${bin}">
                <!--
                 Instrument all the application classes, but
                 don't instrument the test classes.
                 -->
                <include name="**/*.class" />
                <exclude name="**/*Test.class" />
            </fileset>
        </cobertura-instrument>
    </target>

    <property name="testcase" value="edu.depaul.se433.BinarySearchTest" />

    <target name="test2" depends="init,compile">
        <junit fork="yes">
            <!--
             Note the classpath order: instrumented classes are before the
             original (uninstrumented) classes.  This is important.
             -->
            <classpath location="${instrumented}" />
            <classpath location="${bin}" />
            <classpath refid="junit.classpath" />

            <!--
             The instrumented classes reference classes used by the
             Cobertura runtime, so Cobertura and its dependencies
             must be on your classpath.
             -->
            <classpath refid="cobertura.classpath" />

            <formatter type="xml" />

            <test name="${testcase}" todir="${reports.xml}" if="testcase" />
            <batchtest todir="${reports.xml}" unless="testcase">
                <fileset dir="${src}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.java" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>

        <junitreport todir="${reports.xml}">
            <fileset dir="${reports.xml}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="${reports.html}" />
        </junitreport>
    </target>

    <target name="coverage-report-xml">
        <!--
         Generate an XML file containing the coverage data using
         the "srcdir" attribute.
         -->
        <cobertura-report srcdir="${src}" destdir="${coverage.xml}" format="xml" />
    </target>

    <target name="summary-coverage-report">
        <!--
         Generate an summary XML file containing the coverage data using
         the "srcdir" attribute.
         -->
        <cobertura-report srcdir="${src}" destdir="${coverage.summaryxml}" format="summaryXml" />
    </target>

    <target name="coverage-report-html">
        <!--
         Generate a series of HTML files containing the coverage
         data in a user-readable form using nested source filesets.
         -->
        <cobertura-report destdir="${coverage.html}">
            <fileset dir="${src}">
                <include name="**/*.java"/>
                <exclude name="**/*Test.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </cobertura-report>
    </target>

    <target name="coverage" 
    depends="compile,instrument,test2,coverage-report-xml,summary-coverage-report,coverage-report-html" 
    description="Compile, instrument ourself, run the tests and generate JUnit and coverage reports."/>

    <target name="clean">
        <!-- Delete the ${bin} folder -->
        <delete dir="${bin}"/>
        <delete dir="${instrumented}" />
        <delete dir="${reports}" />
        <delete file="cobertura.log" />
        <delete file="cobertura.ser" />
    </target>

</project>
```

And this is my files directory:

```
myProject:
          build.properties
          build.xml
          cobertura-src/cobertura-2.1.1/conbertura files
          junit/
          src/edu/depaul/se433/
```

Comment: What is in build.properties? It looks like cobertura property is set before it is set in the build.xml. (it keeps the first value that is set)